# Tailwind Dynamic Colour Based on Page/URL

Tags: html, css, django, tailwind-css

I was hoping someone new how I could dynamically set text/bg colours based on the current page I'm on? I've brought in a navbar from flowbite and it looks like it designed to highlight a specific option based on the page you're on but I don't quite understand how to make that happen.

I'm using the Tailwind CDN and Flowbite CDNs.

Edit:

I found the "target: ..." option. I've set the id to the url and still nothing.

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've discovered that the url needs to have "#id" for this to work.

However as I'm using Django I have passed a new context to my view which I can pull into my html code to achieve this effect.